# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: c#, exception, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a problem when openning an Access 2003 .mdb file using OleDbConnection.

The customer computer is running windows xp sp3(Just upgraded from windows xp sp2).

I checked this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495/en-us?fr=1#
and the registry is fine.

The code:

```
OleDbConnection _oleDbConn=null;
StringBuilder conn = new StringBuilder();
conn.Append("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=").Append(dataSource).Append(";");
_oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(conn.ToString());
_oleDbConn.Open(); //error occur here
```

Exception:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation
>   generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work
>   was done.

Comment: I get this too. I'm trying to figure it out. I'll be back with any help I find.